# Retrieving tags from XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm trying with jQuery to retrieve the contents of an xml node that contains < ul> and < li> information. The problem I'm having is directly translating that into html, retaining the same structure.

XML:

```
<question num="18">
    <q>JOGs are produced in what two formats? What is the major difference?</q>
    <ans>JOG (Air) and JOG (Ground); the topographical information is identitcal on both, but the ground version shows elevations and contour in meters and the air version shows them in feet. Both versions emphasize airlanding facilities, but the air version has additional symbols to identify aids and obstructions to air navigation. Each version is identified in the lower margin as either Joint Operations Graphic (Air) or Joint Operations Graphic (Ground).</ans>
    <ref>(para 2-6b(4))</ref>
</question>
<question num="19">
    <q>What are some examples of "special" militar maps?</q>
    <ans>Maps designed specifically to show one or more of the following:
        <ul>
            <li>Drainage characteristics</li>
            <li>Climate</li>
            <li>Coasts and landing beaches</li>
            <li>Urban areas</li>
            <li>Electric power</li>
            <li>Fuels</li>
            <li>Water Resources</li>
            <li>Natural construction materials</li>
        </ul>
    </ans>
    <ref>(para 2-6b(8))</ref>
</question>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.get("landnav.xml",{},function(xml){
                $('question', xml).each(function(){
                    questions.push( $(this).find('q').text() );
                    answers.push( $(this).find('ans').contents() );
                });
            });
```

later:

```
$('#answer').click(function(){
                if(sentinal !== undefined){
                    $('#question').html( answers[sentinal] );
                }
            });
```

What's contained in contents seems only to be the 1 and 2, without any `< li>` or `< ul>` tags.

Any thoughts on how I might keep the structure of the node?

Comment: Have you tried content = $(this).find('node').html() ?

Comment: Try `$('#content').append($(content))`.

Comment: would help to see a sample of xml, why make everyone guess

Comment: That's not the issue, though. `contents()` returns a jQuery object containing the children and text nodes of an element. I would do what Bruno recommends and access the node using `html()`.

Comment: Edited code to more closely resemble what I'm working with. I tried pulling the xml with html() instead of contents(), but for some reason the jquery .click stopped working.

Comment: The issue was css. Somehow the display stopped recognizing the list-item structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
// Isolate the XML.
var xmlNode = $(this).find('node');
// Convert the XML structurally to HTML.
// The (true) causes a deep copy.
var htmlFromXml = document.importNode(xmlNode[0], true);
// Append the resulting HTML to the DOM.
$(htmlFromXml).appendTo($('#content'));
```

[`document.importNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.importNode) takes a DOM sub-tree from one document, such as an XML document received via XHR, and creates a structural copy in another document, such as an HTML document.

> **`document.importNode`**
>
> **Summary**
>
> Creates a copy of a node from an external document that can be inserted into the current document.

Comment: Tried your solution:
Append doesn't have the behavior I want. I tried rearranging as $('#question').html(htmlFromXml); but the display is exactly the same as before.

Comment: Why doesn't `append` work?  Maybe [`.replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) or [`.insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) would suffice.

Comment: I want the div contents to be entirely wiped out and replaced with the <ul> I feed it.

Comment: @hyleaus, I don't know which div you mean, but if `theDiv` is a selector for it, then `$(theDiv).replaceWith(htmlFromXml)` should do what you want.